# Getting wrong average in a SQL query

Tags: sql, average

> Question: Find out the average price of PCs and laptops produced by maker A.
>   Result set: one overall average price for all items.
>
> ```
> Database Schema:
> Product(maker, model, type)
> PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)
> Laptop(code, model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
> Printer(code, model, color, type, price)
> ```

I have the following code:

```
with totalproducts
as
(select price 
from pc
where model in (
    select model 
    from product
    where maker='A'
) 
union
select price 
from laptop
where model in (
    select model 
    from product
    where maker='A'
))
select avg(price) from totalproducts
```

However, I get an average of 794.4444 and solution is 754.1666

in: http://www.sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php  Exercise 26

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be better solutions, but to address the problem in your query:

Using `union` without the `all` qualifier removes duplicates, and presumably there might be a pc and a laptop with the same price. Change it to `union all` to keep duplicates from both sets and you'll probably get the expected result.

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, a simpler version looks like this:

```
select avg(price)
from pc
where model in (select model 
                from product
                 where maker='A');
```

Answer (score -1):

Your solution is to use `union all`:

```
SELECT AVG(price) AS price
FROM (SELECT price,'pc' AS type
          FROM pc JOIN product ON product.model=pc.model WHERE maker ='a'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT price, 'laptop' AS type
          FROM laptop JOIN product ON product.model=laptop.model WHERE maker ='a')
   AS tow (price,type)
```